# Rhelp : for loop and arguments

Tags: r, for-loop, pass-by-reference

I want to run something like this about 50 times with different values for varname.

```
Sls_Other_$varname_y1_12 = diff (Sls_Other_$varname_data [,4] , lag=12)
```

$varname should be replaced by a keyword from a sequential list for each iteration of for loop. I tried writing something like this -

```
for ( i in 1:nrow(VarCodes) ) {
  nm<-VarCodes[i]
  Sls_Other_$nm_y1_12 = diff (Sls_Other_$nm_data [,4] , lag=12) }
```

nrow(VarCodes)=50

I'm sure $nm is a wrong reference. I searched on the internet but did not find anything that answers this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `$` function does not evaluate portions of its RHS argument. Need to use "[[".

Answer (score 1):

If you are really sure this succeeds:

```
Sls_Other_$varname_y1_12 = diff (Sls_Other_$varname_data [,4] , lag=12)
# Since the Sls_Other_$varname_data [,4] looks wrong if Sls_Other_ is a dataframe
```

Then probably something along these lines:

```
for ( i in 1:nrow(VarCodes) ) {
  nm<-VarCodes[i]
  Sls_Other_[[paste0(nm, "_y1_12")]] <-  
                    diff (Sls_Other_[[paste0(nm, "_data")]] [,4] , lag=12) }
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a delimited file so [,4] works. however, it seems the way I'm storing the list is not right. what's the ideal format for the list to be read in this manner ? my list is a single column file with 50 rows and is alpha numeric.

Comment: There's no R data structure called "delimited file". You need to post str() on that object.

Comment: I am able to read files using the following -
Sls_Other_Line_949_data= read.delim("C:/file_path/filename.txt", header=TRUE, sep="|", quote="", dec =".")


str(VarCodes)
'data.frame': 49 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 49 levels "BU_601","BU_604",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

Comment: Ok. That makes it (in R) a 'dataframe' and you would not expect this code: `Sls_Other_$varname_data [,4]`  to be acceptable to the parser since there would be no 4th column in the object returned by `Sls_Other_$varname_data` . So you need to explain what you wanted the code to do ... in natural language, since your command of the R language appears rudimentary.

Comment: ok. I guess I need to play around with it some more. All I am trying to do is to read the fourth column of 50 dataframes in 50 unique variables with the same pattern in a recursive manner. I was under the impression R won't be much different than shell syntax. But it is.

Comment: `Sls_Other_ [,4]` would be the fourth column.... of one dataframe. "Shell syntax" may be more of a macro-processed syntax. R is definitely not similar. If you wanted a list of the forth column of a whole bunch of dataframes then you need their names and then use `mget` and then `lapply` on the result.